# Matlab, enlarge a non-uniform object in a binary image

Tags: matlab

I have binary image with non-uniform object. I want to extend this object with 2 pixels around the object's border. What is the best way to enlarge the object using Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.  It's a slight modification of the code in the `imdilate` documentation.

```
N = 2;    % number of pixels to grow the borders

bw = imread('text.png');
se = ones(2*N + 1, 2*N + 1);
bw2 = imdilate(bw,se);
imshow(bw), title('Original')
figure, imshow(bw2), title('Dilated')
```